# Identify Clicked Button In Unordered List: React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I a week new in learning react coming from an angular background. I have the following unordered list in React.

```
const QueueManage: React.FC = () => {
      const { queue, setQueue, loading, error } = useGetQueue();
      const [btnState, setBtnState] = useState(state);
      const enterIconLoading = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>) => {
            const item = '';
            const btn = '';
            console.log(item, btn);
            setBtnState({ loading: true, iconLoading: true, item: item, btnType: btn });
      };

<ul className="listCont">
   {queue.map(queueItem => (
           <li className="col-12" key={queueItem.id}>
               <div className="row">
                                    <div className="listName col-3">
                                        <p>{queueItem.user.firstName} {queueItem.user.lastName}</p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="listName col-5">
                                        <div className="row">
                                            <div className="col-3">
                                                <Button type="primary" loading={btnState.loading} onClick={enterIconLoading}>
                                                    Assign
                                                </Button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="col-3">
                                                <Button type="primary" loading={btnState.loading} onClick={enterIconLoading}>
                                                    Absent
                                                </Button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="col-3">
                                                <Button type="primary" loading={btnState.loading} onClick={enterIconLoading}>
                                                    Done
                                                </Button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="col-3">
                                                <Button type="primary" loading={btnState.loading} onClick={enterIconLoading}>
                                                    Cancel
                                                </Button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </li>
                        )
                        )}
                    </ul>
 }
```

For each list item, the list item will have for buttons, namely Assign, Absent, Done, Cancel. My goal is to identify which button was clicked and for which list item so that I can apply a loader for that specific button. Can any one please assist me with an explanation of how I can achieve this in my code

Here is a visual representation of the list that i get
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zilWE.png[image]

At the moment went i click one button, all buttons are applied a spinner like below: [image]

Your assistance and explanation is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your buttons all have the same method binded to their `onClick` prop.

Comment: Which is why i am asking for the right way to do it. Cant I identify the button clicked in the method

Comment: Yes, you can identify it by passing a parameter to `enterIconLoading` method by doing `onClick={() => enterIconLoading(your_parameter)}`

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Reactful approach involved splitting the `li` into a separate component. This will help keep each item's state separate. Let's call that `QueueItem`.

```
const QueueItem = ({ user }) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

    function onClickAssign() {
        setLoading(true)
        // do something
        setLoading(false)
    }

    function onClickAbsent() {
        setLoading(true)
        // do something
        setLoading(false)
    }

    function onClickDone() {
        setLoading(true)
        // do something
        setLoading(false)
    }

    function onClickCancel() {
        setLoading(true)
        // do something
        setLoading(false)
    }

    return (
        <li className='col-12'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='listName col-3'>
                    <p>
                        {user.firstName} {user.lastName}
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div className='listName col-5'>
                    <div className='row'>
                        <div className='col-3'>
                            <Button type='primary' loading={loading} onClick={onClickAssign}>
                                Assign
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                        <div className='col-3'>
                            <Button type='primary' loading={loading} onClick={onClickAbsent}>
                                Absent
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                        <div className='col-3'>
                            <Button type='primary' loading={loading} onClick={onClickDone}>
                                Done
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                        <div className='col-3'>
                            <Button type='primary' loading={loading} onClick={onClickCancel}>
                                Cancel
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    )
}
```

Here I've also split out each button's `onClick` into a separate callback since they are well defined and probably have unique behaviours. Another approach mentioned above in a comment is

```
function onClickButton(action) {
  ...
}

<Button type='primary' loading={loading} onClick={() => onClickButton('cancel')}>
    Cancel
</Button>
```

This follows the action / reducer pattern which might be applicable here instead of state (`useState`)

Comment: Thank you for explaining and illustrating. I like the 'Reactful' approach better.

Comment: do you need all those functions?, use one function for all the buttons.

Comment: @JuniusL. depends on how complicated the logic is for each button. I would agree with you if the `onClick` method just delegated to other methods depending on `action`, but if the logic for each action is sufficiently complicated, separate functions would be a good idea for readability and testability.

Comment: If i use one function i will find myself doing some switch actions to identify the action taken which might bloat my component  and also there are a lot of things i need to do for each separate action. The component approach seems cleaner

Answer (score 1):

Move the buttons or the whole li to a component and let each list manage it's state.

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState} = React;

//pass the index of li as prop
const Buttons = ({ listId }) => {
  const [clicked, setClickedButton] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        className={clicked === 1 && "Button"}
        onClick={() => setClickedButton(1)}
      >
        Assign
      </button>
      <button  className={clicked === 2 && "Button"} onClick={() => setClickedButton(2)}>Absent</button>
      <button  className={clicked === 3 && "Button"} onClick={() => setClickedButton(3)}>Done</button>
      <button  className={clicked === 4 && "Button"} onClick={() => setClickedButton(4)}>Cancel</button>
    </div>
  );
};


// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Buttons />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<style>
.Button {
  background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
</style>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous answer it's worth adding that making simple components (in our case buttons) stateful is often considered a bad practice as it gets harder to track all the state changes, and to use state from different buttons together (e.g. if you want to disable all 4 buttons in a row after any of them is pressed)

Take a look at the following implementation, where entire buttons state is contained within parent component

```
enum ButtonType {
  ASSIGN, ABSENT, DONE, CANCEL
}

// this component is stateless and will render a button
const ActionButton = ({ label, loading, onClick }) =>
  <Button type="primary" loading={loading} onClick={onClick}>
    {label}
  </Button>



/* inside the QueueManage component */

const [buttonsState, setButtonsState] = useState({})

const updateButton = (itemId: string, buttonType: ButtonType) => {
  setButtonsState({
    ...buttonsState,
    [itemId]: {
      ...(buttonsState[itemId] || {}),
      [buttonType]: {
        ...(buttonsState[itemId]?.[buttonType] || {}),
        loading: true,
      }
    }
  })
}

const isButtonLoading = (itemId: string, buttonType: ButtonType) => {
  return buttonsState[itemId]?.[buttonType]?.loading
}

return (
  <ul className="listCont">
    {queue.map(queueItem => (
        <li className="col-12" key={queueItem.id}>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="listName col-3">
              <p>{queueItem.user.firstName} {queueItem.user.lastName}</p>
            </div>

            <div className="listName col-5">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-3">
                  <ActionButton
                    label={'Assign'}
                    onClick={() => updateButton(queueItem.id, ButtonType.ASSIGN)}
                    loading={isButtonLoading(queueItem.id, ButtonType.ASSIGN)}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="col-3">
                  <ActionButton
                    label={'Absent'}
                    onClick={() => updateButton(queueItem.id, ButtonType.ABSENT)}
                    loading={isButtonLoading(queueItem.id, ButtonType.ABSENT)}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="col-3">
                  <ActionButton
                    label={'Done'}
                    onClick={() => updateButton(queueItem.id, ButtonType.DONE)}
                    loading={isButtonLoading(queueItem.id, ButtonType.DONE)}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="col-3">
                  <ActionButton
                    label={'Cancel'}
                    onClick={() => updateButton(queueItem.id, ButtonType.CANCEL)}
                    loading={isButtonLoading(queueItem.id, ButtonType.CANCEL)}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </li>
      )
    )}
  </ul>
)
```

The goal here is to keep buttons loading state in parent component and manage it from here. `buttonsState` is a multilevel object like

```
{
  '23': {
    [ButtonType.ASSIGN]: { loading: false },
    [ButtonType.ABSENT]: { loading: false },
    [ButtonType.DONE]: { loading: false },
    [ButtonType.CANCEL]: { loading: false },
  },
  ...
}
```

where keys are ids of queueItems and values describe the state of the 4 buttons for that item. It is usually preferred to use [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) instead of nested spreading in `updateButton` but it is good to start with